# Is years in all eras(yugas) calculation related to any increment of sins on earth?

Tags: yuga, sin, kali-yuga, time

We have 4 eras like a Satiyuga, Dwaparayuga, Tretayuga, Kaliyuga.

I have read all of the time periods. But, Is this calculation linked to any other criteria like increment of sins on earth or anything else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the duration (Timeline) of the four "Yugas"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas)

Comment: Time calculation is duplicate but "increment of sins" is not duplicate.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta, I seems that the Qn is edited significantly. If we add [Why did the life expansion(living for many year like 1000 years kept decreasing?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19892/1049), then other part is also answered.

Comment: @iammilind I think OP is asking the differences in each yuga. Time and sin are only two examples. By *anything else*, OP is asking for other things as well.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta anything else is same as etc., I believe. If the question covers anything else, it may become too broad. The author should be specific and it is fine to limit to question to one topic.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Exactly! I was about to say same thing. It's too broad.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta sorry for correcting. You are said my question is too broad. I have just asked criteria. If criteria are more than one than what can I do?

Comment: What you can do is limit the question. For example ask for 5 differences or 6 or any. But make sure that the number is small.

Comment: You should limit the criteria to a single topic. Anything else, etc., should be avoided as much as possible while asking a question. It confuses the users what exactly you are looking for. If the criteria is many, you should ask only 1 or 2 nnot 5 or 6 like @KrishnaShweta said. Including 5 to 6 also gives partial incomplete, partial answers which are not helpful to readers and you. Read https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1176/5212.

Answer (score 3):

From Manu Smriti:

> 1.69. They declare that the Krita age (consists of) four thousand years (of the gods); the twilight preceding it consists of as many
>   hundreds, and the twilight following it of the same number.
>
> 1.70. In the other three ages with their twilights preceding and following, the thousands and hundreds are diminished by one (in each).
>
> 1.71. These twelve thousand (years) which thus have been just mentioned as the total of four (human) ages, are called one age of the
>   gods.
>
> 1.72. But know that the sum of one thousand ages of the gods (makes) one day of Brahman, and that his night has the same length.

So, no, the calculation is not based on the things you've mentioned but solely on some fixed time periods.

But, each Yuga is also typified by certain features like- increase of sins, lack of righteousness or the opposites etc.

> 1.81. In the Krita age Dharma is four-footed and entire, and (so is) Truth; nor does any gain accrue to men by unrighteousness.
>
> 1.82. In the other (three ages), by reason of (unjust) gains (agama), Dharma is deprived successively of one foot, and through (the
>   prevalence of) theft, falsehood, and fraud the merit (gained by men)
>   is diminished by one fourth (in each)
>
> 1.86. In the Krita age the chief (virtue) is declared to be (the performance of) austerities, in the Treta (divine) knowledge, in the
>   Dvapara (the performance of) sacrifices, in the Kali liberality alone.

But, these features, are not contributing in deciding how long the Yugas will be. They are already fixed.

Comment: The OP also knows that there are different calculations in each yuga. The question is how they declared or how they are fixed. Are there any criteria for that.

Comment: @Rickross    1.The calculation is not based on the things you've mentioned but solely on some fixed time periods.

2. Each Yuga is also typified by certain features like- increase of sins, lack of righteousness or the opposites etc.   Both sentence are completly opposite to each other which leads to confusing for me.

Comment: Each Yuga has some typical features. But those features do not determine the length of the Yugas. That is what i have meant @YogeshBorad